# SQL Server: How to calculate the percentage of a table through a join using multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I need to find the percentage of assets that have work order tickets that are open. The following shows the structure of the tables with some dummy data.

```
Assets Table
+---------------------+ 
|  Asset_Number_PK    |
+---------------------+
|  56412              |   
|  56413              |    
|  56414              |  
|  56415              |
+---------------------+ 

Statuses Table    
+-------------------++-------------------+
|  Open_Number      ||  Closed_Number    | 
+-------------------++-------------------+
|  5                ||  8                |             
|  2                ||  7                |        
|  9                ||  11               |        
+-------------------++-------------------+

Work_Orders Table   
+-------------------++-------------------++-------------------+
| WO_Status_Number  || WO_Description    || Asset_number      | 
+-------------------++-------------------++-------------------+
|  5                || Fix air handler   ||  56415            |
|  5                || Replace chiller   ||  56412            |        
|  5                || 2 fans 2nd fl     ||  56414            |       
|  7                || 4 fans 2nd fl     ||  56414            |    
|  7                || Fix Air duct      ||  56413            |  
+-------------------++-------------------++-------------------+
```

I've tried the following two queries to calculate the percentage but my output is incorrect:

```
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(Asset_Number_PK) AS tol_open_assets " 
sql = sql & "FROM Assets WHERE Asset_Number_PK IN (SELECT a.Asset_Number " 
sql = sql & "FROM Work_Orders a, Statuses b, Assets c " 
sql = sql & "WHERE a.WO_Status_Number = b.Open_Number AND a.Asset_Number = c.Asset_Number_PK)"
myRs.Open sql,con,1,2
if myRs.eof then
 tol_open_assets = 0
else
 tol_open_assets = myRs("tol_open_assets")
end if
myRs.Close


sql = "SELECT COUNT(Asset_Number_PK) AS tol_assets FROM Assets"
myRs.Open sql,con,1,2
tol_assets = myRs("tol_assets")
myRs.Close

if tol_assets = 0 then
 tol_asset_percentage = 0
else
 tol_asset_percentage = round(100*tol_open_assets/tol_assets,0)
end if

response.write(tol_asset_percentage)
```

Comment: In your query you use column `Asset_Number`, yet this column does not exist in your `Assets` table definition. Is column `Asset_Number` nullable? FYI: `COUNT( col_name )` does not count `NULL` values.

Comment: @Alex sorry that's a typo. I'll edit that now

Comment: Based on the sample, I do not see a way how this query can produce more than 100% results. Have you tried checking intermediate values: tol_open_assets, tol_asset_percentage?

Comment: @Alex I'm agree with you, but I spotted something wrong in the first line, it should be `sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Asset_Number_PK) AS tol_open_assets "`

Comment: I have noticed `DISTINCT COUNT()` as well. It is not the only odd thing about your query though: you use Non-ANSI joins as well. Assuming that Asset_Number_PK is a primary key and cannot contain duplicates, then it should not matter.

Comment: You also did not answer my previous question: "Is column Asset_Number nullable?"

Comment: @Alex it's not nullable and I checked the values it's not over 100% but the percentages are incorrect because one asset can be on many work order tickets

Comment: In you your question you are asking to count assets that have at least one "open" work order ticket (that's how I read it). And as far as I can see this is what the query does. Please clarify your problem?

Comment: Is it possible to add more records to demonstrate the issue of percentage > 100%? Using the sample record provided above, both the counts are 1 resulting in the output value as 100%.

Comment: @Alex what I will do is add more dummy data to refer to what I am talking about and take out the table structure

Comment: Please create http://sqlfiddle.com/ and post the link in your question.

Comment: @Alex I've changed the tables and I will provide the sqlfiddle

Comment: Also post expected output i.e. that value / values you are want to get.

Comment: @Alex I working with a lot of data so using the sqlfiddle does not help me. I'm getting a value of 1. At least with my real data I atleast get a percentage and I can't provide the actual data for other reasons and limitations. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c78f97/1/0

Comment: @michaeld54 - SQL fiddle helps us. :) Also we do not need a full data set just a representative sample and the percentage you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Your result (75 based on your data) appears **correct**.

You could determine the percentage of open assets in a single query as well:

```
SELECT 
  PercentOpen = SUM(COALESCE(openOrder.IsOpen, 0)) / COUNT(*) * 100
FROM Assets a
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 IsOpen = CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
  FROM Work_Orders wo 
  JOIN Statuses s ON wo.WO_Status_Number = s.Open_Number
  WHERE wo.Asset_Number = a.Asset_Number_PK
) openOrder
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/abb85/36)

Comment: Your solution looks promising I think you maybe on to something. I will try your query and test some filters with it. I'm not sure if either one of us is correct because I was told my solution is incorrect, so I'm looking for other solutions. For this question I left out the filters of the other tables to find the foundation of the query. Also, I'm handling A LOT of assets, over 10000.